# calculate months by name and respective days between two dates

Tags: excel, vba, days

I need is a simple VBA code which will tell me the names of months between two dates and respective days in those months, like this below. It should automatically add rows if needed between two dates. 
If anyone can write a code for excel VBA, I would be so thankful.

```
START DATE 20/10/2017   END DATE 15/10/2018
Oct-17  11
Nov-17  30
Dec-17  31
Jan-18  31
Feb-18  28
Mar-18  31
Apr-18  30
May-18  31
Jun-18  30
Jul-18  31
Aug-18  31
Sep-18  30
Oct-18  15
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. from your public profile, we can see you haven't taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet. I suggest you do so and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can then come back here and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53599854/edit) to let us know what you have tried so far and how it fails to achieve your desired goal

Comment: When asking a question like this, you should always include what you tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: This can be done with two formulas, without the need for vba.

Comment: can u explain how with formula.

Comment: Can you show how you would try?

Comment: Although I think that this is the perfect title for this post, it might be little unclear what it is all about. An alternate description might be that this is actually the number of days between two dates split up by month: If you subtract the older date from the newer one or if you sum up the results of column B, you'll get 360 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the First Column put this and copy down:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1)+ROW(1:1)-1,1)<$B$1,DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1)+ROW(1:1)-1,1),"")
```

Then in the next Column put:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=MONTH($A$1),YEAR(A2)=YEAR($A$1)),EOMONTH(A2,0)-$A$1,IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=MONTH($B$1),YEAR(A2)=YEAR($B$1)),$B$1-EOMONTH(A2,-1),DAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)))),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

You will need to format the First column `mmm-yy`

Comment: cant thank enough, that is exactly what i needed, thanks man.

Comment: is there anyway to hide rows which are empty?

Comment: That you cannot do with formula.  It will need vba or manually done.

Comment: i think i am happy with what you taught me, thanks once again.

Comment: If this worked for you then please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.